# Delay in microSD loading causes null value on first load

Tags: android, file-io

I store the various user accounts in a custom Object *ArrayList* saved in a file on microSD card, and I load this file with the follow method:

```
public static ArrayList<User> loadAllUsers() {
        if (storageAvailable()) {
            ArrayList<User> myList = new ArrayList<User>();
            try {
                FileInputStream myListUsersSaved = new FileInputStream(baseDir
                        + File.separator + fileName);

                ObjectInputStream myListUsers = new ObjectInputStream(
                        myListUsersSaved);

                myList = (ArrayList<User>) myListUsers.readObject();

                myListUsers.close();

            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }

            return myList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

This usually works fine, but unfortunately in some slow devices, the first load attempt fail, probably due to delay in accessing the data on microSD, and when I open the activity that load the various profiles saved, the first time the method returns *null* and this seems empty, if I try to reload the activity the second time, no problem.

Any suggestion to avoid the issue?

Comment: You probably should not store account details on the external storage, as that is not only unreliably present as you have found, but open to be read or even modified by pretty much any other app on the system.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You are right but what is saved in the file aren't sensible data, but only some cached infos.

Comment: @Sivlerstorm - it's still probably the wrong location.  Or are you talking about many megabytes of information?

Comment: @ChrisStratton
Not huge amount of megabytes but there are also some Base64 images in the "User" object. So I don't see a better storage location.

Comment: Content type does not dictate external location, only size or need to handoff via intents to picky apps might.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know, but usually some content as images require more space than simple text. More low-end devices come with very poor internal memory. What is the vantage in use internal memory in my case?

Comment: Reliable presence.  Potential privacy, at least to the degree that the security model remains intact permitting anything to be called private.

Comment: For the privacy as I have said there aren't sensible data in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay happens only in some rare modded firmwares that move all device memory to microSD. The solution is return to stable firmware or load twice times the method.

Comment: If you mean that the "internal" storage is ending up external, yes that could be problematic.  But separate that from using external storage when you should have used internal.